# How do I remove an array from a list of arrays based on criteria?

Tags: python, arrays

The output from my model gives me an array of 60 values (1 per timestep). I run my model 5 times (Python) so I can obtain a mean value for each timestep across the 5 repetitions. However, I am trying to calculate the mean for ONLY the repetitions that do not consist of a value that is below 0.0001.

Right now, I have:

```
count=0
repetitions=[]

while count <= 4:
    rank=np.loadtxt(f"rank_{count}_prev")
    count=count+1
    repetitions.append(rank)
    print(repetitions)  # Five arrays

count=0
while count <=59:  # 60 values in each array
    for rank in repetitions:
        for value in rank:
            if value < 0.0001:
                del rank
                count += 1
            else:
                count += 1
```

This gives me the error:

> NameError: name 'rank' is not defined.
> Or I try:

```
for value in rank:
    if value < 0.0001:
        repetitions.remove(rank)
        count += 1
    else:
        count += 1
```

This gives me the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

But I am not looking to get true/false statements out of this.

Last, I have tried:

```
new_reps = []

for value in rank:
    if value > 0.0001:
        new_reps.append(rank)
        count+=1
    else: 
        count+=1
```

This gives me a list of 237 arrays, which makes me think that for each  of the 60 values in a rank (array) that is greater than 0.0001, it adds that array to the new matrix.

I cannot seem to make any of these attempts work. Can anyone help me either fix one of my attempts or provide their own solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `filter` function is a nifty way to remove elements. The `any` fucntion will return true if any of the elements are satisfied.

```
filtered_means = list(map(np.mean, filter(lambda lst: not any(i < 0.0001 for i in lst), repetitions)))
```

Comment: This calculates the mean of the 60 values within each array that does not have a value < 0.0001. The second part is what I am looking for (thank you!!), but now I need to take the mean across the remaining arrays at each timestep (i.e., if 3 arrays match this criterion, I need a mean at each timestep (60) across the 3 repetition arrays).

Comment: Can you clarify what the output is that you're looking for in your question?

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out using the filter tool you suggested: 
```
filtered = list(filter(lambda lst: not any(i < 0.0005397 for i in lst), repetitions))
```
I just needed the original arrays, but only the ones that met the criterion! And then I will take the mean for each of the 60 values, such as np.mean(filtered, axis=0). 
Thanks so much for responding and helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use numpy's boolean indexing for this:

```
for count in range(5)
    rank=np.loadtxt(f"rank_{count}_prev")
    rank = rank[rank > 0.0001]
    repetitions.append(rank)
    print(repetitions)  # Five arrays
```

Comment: I thought this worked but no luck! It only pulls out the values within each array that are greater than the specified value. For example, the first and fourth arrays came back empty, the second came back with 4 values, the third with 8, and the last with 6. Any thoughts? Thanks for the fast response, by the way!!

Comment: That's what I thought you wanted.  What were you expecting?

Comment: No worries! I had a hard time describing it. I just needed the entire arrays, but only the ones that had no values smaller than 0.0001. I was able to do that using the filter tool: " filtered = list(filter(lambda lst: not any(i < 0.0005397 for i in lst), repetitions)) "
Then I need to take the mean across arrays at each timestep (60 timesteps/values within each array), so I will do this by: "np.mean(filtered, axis=0)." Thanks so much for your time and help!